# Pandas: drop both rows if one column matches same and another don't

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to drop both rows in a pandas data frame where the value in one column(account) is not duplicate and the value in some other column (recharge_number) is duplicate given A. An illustrative example:

```
data = {'account': [43,43,43,43,45,45], 
    'recharge_number': [17777, 17777, 17999, 17888, 17222, 17999] , 
    'year': [2021,2021,2021,2021,2020,2020], 
    'month': [2,3,5,6,2,9]}
```

```
account  recharge_number   year  month
43        17777            2021    2
43        17777            2021    3
43        17999            2021    5    
43        17888            2021    6    
45        17222            2020    2
45        17999            2020    9
```

[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soXHR.png)

output:

```
account  recharge_number   year  month
43        17777            2021    2
43        17777            2021    3    
43        17888            2021    6    
45        17222            2020    2
```

[output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC8xz.png)

Comment: Shouldn't "7 40" be dropped according to your conditions?

Comment: @mozway, No, actually. My concern is if any duplicate value (NUMBER) appears in a different ID column then both of the data will be dropped. As "7 40" only appears once, it won't drop.

Comment: Ok @asif I fixed it, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with `.crosstab`:

```py
mask = pd.crosstab(df["account"], df["recharge_number"]).ne(0).sum().gt(1)
print(df[~df["recharge_number"].isin(mask[mask].index)])
```

Prints:

```
   account  recharge_number  year  month
0       43            17777  2021      2
1       43            17777  2021      3
3       43            17888  2021      6
4       45            17222  2020      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want "the full row (or the two columns if larger dataframe) is duplicated" or "number is not duplicated"

You can use `duplicated`:

```
df[df['id', 'number'].duplicated(keep=False)|~df['number'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
   id  number
0   5      10
1   5      10
3   6      20
5   7      40
```

Comment: My concern is if any duplicate value (NUMBER) appears in a different ID column then both of the data will be dropped. But here, the output is quite opposite.

Comment: @asifabdullah Have you checked the updated answer?

Comment: According to observation by someone, the serial downvotes victims are those questions that don't show efforts of attempts to solve the questions by the OP themselves.  The hangman tries also to discourage people answering such questions by downvoting all answers too  :-(

Comment: @mozway, sorry. i can't get my desired output. It's my bad i didn't explain it in detail. My dataset is something like that. But your answer didn't help in this situation. Again sorry for my bad explanation.                                                                                        
        data = {'account': [43,43,43,43,45,45], 
        'recharge_number': [17777, 17777, 17999, 17888, 17222, 17999] , 
        'year': [2021,2021,2021,2021,2020,2020], 
        'month': [2,3,5,6,2,9]}

Comment: You need to add the column names. Full code: `df[df['account', 'recharge_number'].duplicated(keep=False)|~df['recharge_number'].duplicated(keep=False)]`

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to drop rows instead of keep them:

```
>>> df.drop(df[~df.duplicated(['id', 'number'], keep=False)
               & df.duplicated('number', keep=False)].index)

   id  number
0   5      10
1   5      10
3   6      20
5   7      40
```

The first condition protect all duplicate ('id', 'number') records. The second condition remove all records where 'number' are the same.

Comment: I'm not OP, but I think he wants `40` and not `30` because `30` appeared in group `5` and `7`

Comment: @Corralien,  My goal is that any customer (ID) has a different mobile number (number). But if the same mobile number (number) appears in a different customer (ID) then both of the data should be dropped. I hope you understand.

Comment: Also, don't forget `keep=False` or you'll miss the first duplicated item ;)

Comment: I fully understand now. @mozway has the right answer.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same.